# Configuring Apache2 to Auto redirect calls to port 80 to port 443

Tags: apache-http-server, https, ubuntu-server, mod-rewrite

I am running an Ubuntu 12.04 Server-based Apache2 server with SSL. I seem to have my configuration correct to achieve SSL connections over port 443, and at first, I did not even configure the server for ANY VirtualHost on port 80.

Now, I would like to configure the server to take any HTTP requests over port 80 and automatically redirect them my port 443 virtualhosts, 100% of the time.

The one tip I am currently attempting is to use a .htaccess file in every directory with the following rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

What is the barebones VirtualHost *:80 necessary to achieve correct redirects to *:443?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
RedirectMatch ^/(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1
```

in the virtual host.

You'd need to set a DocumentRoot to some place so that there's a fallback in case mod_alias is acting up.

Comment: thanks! also, for posterity, don't forget to remove https-related rewrite rules in .htaccess files if necessary.